# Has there been any research on time-windowed spectral estimation using more than one window function at the same time?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

In the Welch's method, a signal is divided into overlapping segments, multiplied with a window function, and transformed to frequency domain via fourier transform.

Why does the method use only one window function? Suppose I would use (say) ten window functions to produce ten spectral estimates. By averaging the estimates, my SNR would be higher than by using just one of the windows?

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want to apply more than one window function to the same frame of signal???

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations! Sounds like you are about to reinvent the [multitaper method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitaper), in which a number of orthogonal window functions are used to get independent spectral estimates that are then averaged (with weights). A suitable window function family are the Slepian sequences:

[image: Slepian window functions]